# django softlayer object storage, what backend or package should i use?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-storage, cloud-storage

I'm using django and I want to use SoftLayer object storage to store my mp3 files. http://www.softlayer.com/cloudlayer/storage

I can't figure out what backend in django-storages ([django-storages.readthedocs.org](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) should i use. And how to tell django to look into softlayer.com after choosing a backend.

If someone can suggest another django package, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose RackSpace CloudStorage. I'm using package [django-cumulus](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus) + [SoftLayer object storage](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python) python library. After subclassing CloudFilesStorage and making some changes due to softlayer api difference - it works for me